# Mounting Azure Blob Storage to Azure Databricks without using cluster

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

We have a requirement that while  provisioning the Databricks service thru CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps we should able to mount a blob storage to DBFS without connecting to a cluster. Is it possible to mount object storage to DBFS cluster by using a bash script from Azure DevOps ?

I looked thru various forums but they all mention about doing this using **dbutils.fs.mount** but the problem is we cannot run this command in Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline.

Will appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is possible but it requires a bit of extra work. In our organisation we've tried various approaches and I've been working with Databricks for a while. The solution that works best for us is to write a bash script that makes use of the databricks-cli in your Azure Devops pipeline. The approach we have is as follows:

1. Retrieve a Databricks token using the token API
2. Configure the Databricks CLI in the CI/CD pipeline
3. Use Databricks CLI to upload a mount script
4. Create a Databricks job using the Jobs API and set the mount script as file to execute

The steps above are all contained in a bash script that is part of our Azure Devops pipeline.

**Setting up the CLI** 
Setting up the Databricks CLI without any manual steps is now possible since you can generate a temporary access token using the Token API. We use a Service Principal for authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/tokens

**Create a mount script** 
We have a scala script that follows the mount instructions. This can be Python as well. See the following link for more information:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#mount-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-filesystem.

**Upload the mount script**
In the Azure Devops pipeline the databricks-cli is configured by creating a temporary token using the token API. Once this step is done, we're free to use the CLI to upload our mount script to DBFS or import it as a notebook using the Workspace API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace#--import

**Configure the job that actually mounts your storage**
We have a JSON file that defines the job that executes the "mount storage" script. You can define a job to use the script/notebook that you've uploaded in the previous step. You can easily define a job using JSON, check out how it's done in the Jobs API documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#--

At this point, triggering the job should create a temporary cluster that mounts the storage for you. You should not need to use the web interface, or perform any manual steps.

You can apply this approach to different environments and resource groups, as do we. For this we make use of Jinja templating to fill out variables that are environment or project specific.

I hope this helps you out. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi J.Offenberg, Thanks for sharing this information. The catch here is that we will not have any token for connecting to Databricks workspace after it is provisioned thru an ARM template, so how will the token get generated or how will the bash script authorize to generate the token thru token api ?

Comment: Also, if you can share an example of the running a simple python script thru this job, either using spark-submit or JAR option it will be really helpful.

Comment: Our Databricks environment is also provisioned via ARM. We use a service principal to request an access token. This link shows you how to obtain a token using a service principal. There is also a Bash example of the request. Let me know if this helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token

Comment: @NGupta any luck solving your case? Could you accept the answer if it helped you out?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the inputs, it helped us a lot. Just a quick input - can we use an init script in the cluster to check if the mount point is available and if not then the mount point can be created ? What is your thought on it ?

Comment: In principle, if you mount your storage during provisioning you should not have to do it again. I personally would not use an init script for this.

Comment: Hi J.Offenberg, we were trying the accomplish this using below steps:
1. Provision a Databricks Service using the ARM template
2. Create a Service Principal and grant it access to Databricks Service which is provisioned in Step 1.
3. Get the Service Principal Access token using the API.
4. Generate the Databricks Access token using Service principal access token (This is where we are facing issues)
5. We will use the Databricks Access token generated in Step 4 to upload a mount script.
6. The Script will be executed using Databricks Job which will  mount the Azure Blob storage to DBFS.

Comment: Hi @NGupta, I recommend following the steps as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token. You can do the request in Azure Devops using your bash script and use the retrieved token to set up the CLI. This link has some code examples that you can use. Note that if you're playing around with the token, it expires after a bit (the request specifies the time). Let me know if this helped you.